# Unsorted array with multiple missing numbers

Tags: java

Given an array by size N with multiple missing numbers which equals to -1 i need to find the missing numbers and print the updated array , all the number in the array from [1-n] , not allowed to sort the array

I've tries to solve it on paper first but couldn't

Example:
Array[2,4,6,5,-1,8,-1]

Results:
[2,4,6,5,3,8,7] or [2,4,6,5,3,8,7] either of them is good and its supposed to be linier time complexity

Even a hint would help for how to implement the finding of the missing numbers

Comment: The two arrays you posted seem me equals.

Comment: "Either of them is good" why don't either contain 1?

Comment: @AndyTurner because only two are missing and that would mean that 1,3, and 7 are missing since the max is 8 and they need to constitute a range.

Comment: @WJS what does "all in number in the array from [1-n]" mean then?

Comment: @AndyTurner  I think that was showing the values of a legitimate range.  So any subrange of [1-n] would be valid.

Comment: @WJS in which case an array of size 7 shouldn't contain 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Populate a bit set with the numbers 1-n:

```
BitSet bits = new BitSet(n + 1);
bits.set(1, n + 1, true);
```

Iterate the array, unset bits in the BitSet which are not -1:

```
for (int b : arr) {
  if (b != -1) bits.clear(b);
}
```

Iterate the array and replace -1s with a set bit from the BitSet:

```
for (int a = 0, prev = 0; a < arr.length; ++a) {
  if (arr[a] == -1) {
    arr[a] = prev = bits.nextSetBit(prev + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: In practice, for anything but insanely large data sets, this will probably work more efficiently than my map solution.  But in theory, this probably does not have a linear running time, because the `nextSetBit()` function probably performs a linear search for the next bit.  (I don't know that for sure, but I cannot imagine how else they could have implemented it.)  So, the time complexity of `nextSetBit()` is a function of `N`, and subsequently the time complexity of the loop over `N` where `nextSetBit()` is used is `N` squared.

Comment: @MikeNakis no, it's still linear. You don't have to  search from the start of the bit set each time.

Comment: Well, the inner loop in bubble-sort does not start from the beginning of the array each time either, but it is still considered a `O(N^2)` algorithm. That's because it does not matter whether it starts from the beginning, what matters is whether the number of iterations is a function of `N` or not.

Comment: @MikeNakis even with a terrible implementation of `nextSetBit`, this would only check each of the N bits in the BitSet once. It's definitely linear.

Answer (score 0):

`O(c*N)` is still linear time when `c` is a constant. This means that the "Linear time" requirement still allows you to do multiple passes over the array, as long as the number of passes is constant. (As long as the number of passes is not a function of `N`.)

So:

Pass 1: populate a map with all values, both missing and present.

Pass 2: remove from the map each value which can be found in the array.

Pass 3: replace each `-1` in the array with a number from the map, removing that number from the map.

Comment: Opps.  Looks like I did it.  Went away for awhile.  Must have been an accident.  If you edit your answer I will amend the vote.  So sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's my attempt.  It has to do more bookkeeping than I originally thought.

```
        int[] vals = { 2, -1,6,-1,-1};
        // min value is the start of the sequence
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int bitmap = 0;
        // records the -1 indices.
        List<Integer> missing = new ArrayList<>();

        // loops at most n times.
        for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
            int v = vals[i];
            if (v >= 0) {
                // set value in bitmap 
                bitmap |= (1 << v);
                // and find minimum entry
                if (v < min) {
                    min = v;
                }
            } else {
                // save index of missing numbers.
                missing.add(i);
            }
        }

        // get rid of low order zero bits.
        bitmap>>=min;

        int i = 0;
        // Loops at most, n times
        while(!missing.isEmpty()) {
            // check bitmap for a missing number in sequence
            if ((bitmap & 1) == 0) {
                // and fill it in
                vals[missing.get(0)] = i + min;
                missing.remove(0);
            }
            bitmap>>=1;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));
```